How to detect pressing youtube button on remote control
I am developing an Android tv app. I need to catch YouTube button press and disable it. I need to do the same for Netflix, Amazon etc.
This is a parental app that serves as a launcher app. I did the launcher part, i am able to capture back press and override it. Now i need to handle the buttons i mention.
Any help would be appreciated.
I asked chatgpt and other llms but they couldn't help. There is no documentation either.

You will probably have to create an AccessibilityService and listen to key events in the service with onKeyEvent to find the key and block it (its not going to be the same key code for every device).

Note that there is no requirement for those buttons to be surfaced as key events for you to block, just as a packet coming in on WiFi is not going to be surfaced as a key event for you to block. Also, please bear in mind that the number and type of buttons offered by an Android TV's remote will vary by device model, so unless you plan on individually testing every single Android TV device model (past/present/future), it is unclear how you will meet your objective.

Let's think in reverse.that is, how to allow the user to press only numbers and 4-way navigation buttons. All other key presses would be ignored. How to manage this?
